# Set up a global array in public and then fill it in a private sub

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to dimension an array of strings [public] so that the entire app can see it global but then FILL it in a private sub. Here is my code. It is not throwing an error or exception YET it is not filling the array and when I ask for array contents, it then does throw an error and say the array is empty.

```
Public arrErrorKeyWords As New List(Of String)

Private Sub FillIt()
   Dim strErrorKeyWords As String = ""
   strErrorKeyWords = strErrorKeyWords & "sql"
   strErrorKeyWords = strErrorKeyWords & "could not open"
   strErrorKeyWords = strErrorKeyWords & "error"
   arrErrorKeyWords.AddRange(Split(strErrorKeyWords, ","))
End Sub
```

Ideas?

Comment: What's the exact error message?  That will likely lead you to finding an existing solution

Comment: Splitting on a comma, but I don't see any commas in the key word list.  Just add the words to arrErrorKeyWords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to populate it by constructing a CSV string and then splitting it into an array. However you have not included the delimiter.

You could do:

```
Public arrErrorKeyWords As New List(Of String)

Private Sub FillIt()
   Dim strErrorKeyWords As String = ""
   strErrorKeyWords = strErrorKeyWords & "sql" & ","
   strErrorKeyWords = strErrorKeyWords & "could not open" & ","
   strErrorKeyWords = strErrorKeyWords & "error"
   arrErrorKeyWords.AddRange(Split(strErrorKeyWords, ","))
End Sub
```

Or more efficiently you could simply do:

```
Public arrErrorKeyWords As New List(Of String)

Private Sub FillIt()
    arrErrorKeyWords.Add("sql")
    arrErrorKeyWords.Add("could not open")
    arrErrorKeyWords.Add("error")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use Public variables in Private methods and vice versa. Inside the class their behavior is identical. The difference is in member visibility *outside* of your class.

You cannot intersect shared with non-shared though.

The code you posted works fine for me. After executing `FillIt`, `arrErrorKeyWords` has one element with this string as content: "sqlcould not openerror". If you want further help, please clarify your original intent.

As is, I would assume you are trying to handle an SQL exception. My advise is to use `ex.Message.ToString`, instead of trying to substitute with a user friendly message. These errors don't happen very often, but when they do, you really want to see the *original* exception text, cause it helps you greatly in troubleshooting the issue.